# How to generate 3 unique fractions without being reducable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to generate 3 fractions with these rules:

- denominator is the same
- numerator must be unique and between 1 and denominator * 3
- Fraction must not be reducable (for example: 2 / 6 can be reduced to 1 /3 which ins't allowed)

I already have a function to generate unique numertors

```
static randomUnique(range: number, count: number) {
  let nums: number[] = [];
  while (nums.length < count) {
    nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (range) + 1));
  }
  return [...nums];
}
```

and a function to check if the fraction is reducable

```
static isSimplified(numOne: number, numTwo: number) {
        let numerator = numOne;
        let denominator = numTwo;
        for (let i = Math.max(numOne, numTwo); i > 1; i--) {
            if ((numOne % i === 0) && (numTwo % i === 0)) {
                numOne /= i;
                numTwo /= i;
            }
        }
        return numOne === numerator && numTwo === denominator ? false : true;
    }
```

The problem is that the generated numerators can be reducable so I changed the `randomUnique` function to this

```
static randomUnique(denominator: number, count: number) {
    let nums: number[] = [];
    let numerator = 0;

    while ((nums.length < count)) {
        numerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * (denominator * 3) + 1);
        if (!FractionAxisLogic.isSimplified(numerator, denominator))
            nums.push(numerator);
    }
    return [...nums];
}
```

And now the problem that `numerators` aren't unique

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing `let nums: number[] = [];` to using javascript `Set()` which is an object for storing unique values.